# Has anyone got a proven recipe to attenuate wi-fi with a Faraday cage?

Tags: faraday-cage

I need to put a domestic wi-fi router in a homemade Faraday cage that will severely attenuate the signal. Has anyone actually DONE this?

There is lots of good advice of what should work, but  few reports of what actually did work.

The nearest, on Youtube, is someone putting the router in three big nested heavy metal trash cans. That works good, but I've got no room for kit that bulky.

A great-sounding suggestion is to cover a box in 2 layers of aluminium foil, so there is high capacitance between the two layers.  I tried this and it didn't work, maybe because I re-used old foil and it wasn't flat enough.

In general aluminium foil is useless - it is like Wile E. Coyote and the Road Runner, the signal just laughs at it.

Perforated metal sheet a few mm thick is meant to work. If no answers here that will be my next attempt, but I'd love to know if anyone has actually done this in any way.

Many thanks

Comment: Tried microwave yet?

Comment: Microwave oven, if you can get the power cable through the door - or power from a big battery that you put in the oven with it.

Comment: Now, when you got some votes.. why do you need it at all?

Comment: Just remove the antenna and replace with 50 Ohm resistors in SMA plugs.  That's what we did for burn in tests.  I didn't even  have to use my Lindgren Cage for that.

Comment: Hehe. I just found [this link](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8279549.stm). Looks like a lot of tin foil hat fun. But who knows? Might be as easy as painting your box. ;)

Answer (score 4):

A common microwave oven is specifically designed to block the frequency band used by wi-fi, bluetooth, cellular data networks, and various other wireless communication protocols. This is because the microwave oven operates at the same frequency band; that's why microwaves can interfere with wifi.

A cheap microwave, or even a non-functional one, is probably the easiest way to get a good Faraday cage of this type. Either put a battery in the microwave with the device, or cut a small hole to feed a power cord through; the hole will cause leakage, but it shouldn't be too much.

As for being a proven recipe... Well, the fact that you don't feel hot standing in front of the microwave is evidence enough, no? If you need more, just stick a cell phone in the microwave and try to call it. It won't ring. (as mentioned above, cell phones and wifi use the same frequency band)

Comment: "evidence enough, no?", hm, not really in itself, to be honest! A meagre overall 40 dB attenuation would ensure that of the ~1kW inside the oven only 100 mW leave it – which would be the same power as a legal wifi device in the EU  (or 1/10 of what's allowed in the US), and you don't feel your hand get warm when you hold it in front of a phone or access point, either. But: you still got some 60 to 120 dB of acceptable power loss before the device really can't do wifi anymore

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fair point! But the asker didn't say what they considered "severely attenuated", I suppose.

Comment: But, I've just tried: closing the door on the microwave oven leads to reliable connection loss, so this particular oven is **way** better than it has to be in terms of isolation, legally: German Bundesamt für Strahlenschutz (Federal Agency for Radiation Safety) [says](https://www.bfs.de/DE/themen/emf/hff/quellen/mikrowelle/mikrowelle.html) 5mW/cm² in emissions is OK for microwave ovens, and boy, does a microwave oven have many square centimeters

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah, I've used cell phones inside microwave ovens to demonstrate the idea of a Faraday cage more than once, they're pretty reliable as such!

Comment: "On average, the leakage radiation was 1 % of the specified limit value on the device surface. These results were found on old as well as modern devices on the market. **With increasing distance from the device, the intensity of the high-frequency fields quickly decreases**. At a distance of 30 centimeters, for example, about five to ten percent of the microwave intensity measured on the surface of the device is still present; at a distance of one meter this value has dropped to a thirtieth to a hundredth."

Comment: if you disassemble the oven you can probably run cables though the vents  but to get them though you'll probably have to cut the plugs off and replace or re-attach them.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you, this seems good.  I ran an internet speed test with my phone inside the office microwave and it said "Network failure", a perfect result. I'll report back when I get an old microwave to try the actual router, with cables, at home.

I also made a kind of cryogenic discovery because I learned that - and this exactly happened - that if you open the microwave in the office kitchen at the precise moment that the building maintenance guy walks past and says "Hi Andrew", and you take out your mobile phone, the temperature in the room drops 10 degrees!

Comment: OK, "microwave cooker" is not the answer to this question.  I finally got hold of an old microwave at home (UK.) And on my Android phone I used a signal meter, "Mobile Signal Tracker Pro" by KAIBITS Software GmbH. You can read this through the door of the cooker.

With both mobile signal and microwave, putting the mobile inside the cooker gives a reduction of about 20 dBm, ish. Earthing the cooker only makes small difference. Youtube videos play fine inside the closed cooker, long after any initial buffering. Putting the router inside (small crack in door) and the mobile outside is similar.

Comment: My comment from Dec 17 2019 was a false positive. The signals outside my office microwave are already very weak, so -20 dBm is enough to result in "network failure."

Comment: @AndrewWhite I'm concerned about that microwave oven, then. Seems likely to give you cataracts or something from the leakage if you use it.

Comment: @Hearth I did wonder about putting a jar full of water outside it and seeing if it got warm!  I just this minute did a very quick test on another microwave in my office and got only about 15 dBm reduction. I assume - I hope -  that maybe the shielding in the cooker is tuned to work for the exact frequency of the microwaves - in my office it says 2450Mhz. Yes, it doesn't look good.